# Type and property to be used for population, land area, and population density

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have scanned through the official docs to find the type and properties to be used for population, land area, and population density, but found none. The closest I can see seems to be [`PropertyValue`](http://schema.org/PropertyValue), [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue), or [`Number`](http://schema.org/Number) for both population and population density, and [`area`](http://schema.org/area) for land area, though all of these are vague.

The problem is that the docs says that area should only be used on type `BroadcastService`. And there aren't any tips on which property and type to use on population and population density.

I have tried doing this but am unsure if it is correct:

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea'>
  <li>Village: <span itemprop='name'>San Jose</span></li>
  <li><span itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PropertyValue'>Population (2016): <span itemprop='value'>15,437</span></span></li>
  <li><span itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PropertyValue'>Land area: <span itemprop='value'>51.41<</span> <span itemprop='unitText'>square kilometers</span></span></li>
  <li><span itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PropertyValue'>Population density</span>: <span itemprop='value'>300</span> <span itemprop='unitText'>per square kilometer</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *add* (relate/connect) the `PropertyValue` items to the `AdministrativeArea` item. Simply nesting HTML elements [doesn’t affect the Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897888/1591669). You add items by using a property (in Microdata with `itemprop`). In this case, you’ll want to use the [`additionalProperty`](http://schema.org/additionalProperty) property:

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea'>
  <li><span itemprop='additionalProperty' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PropertyValue'><!-- … --></li>
  <li><span itemprop='additionalProperty' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PropertyValue'><!-- … --></li>
  <li><span itemprop='additionalProperty' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PropertyValue'><!-- … --></li>
</ul>
```

Within a `PropertyValue`, you should specify the name with the [`name`](http://schema.org/name) property, otherwise the items only have a value and a unit text, but it wouldn’t be clear what the value is for.

```html
<span itemprop='name'>Population (2016)</span>

<span itemprop='name'>Land area</span>

<span itemprop='name'>Population density</span>
```